# How do I disable the sudo paste warning?

Tags: command-line, root

How can I disable this popup?

[image]

I can't find any settings.

Comment: use middle-click paste it has never come when you paste with middle-click

Comment: @Adityaultra that's a bug rather than a feature I believe: https://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-terminal/+bug/1444145

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Run this command in terminal to disable:

```
gsettings set org.pantheon.terminal.settings unsafe-paste-alert false
```

and then this to re-enable it:

```
gsettings set org.pantheon.terminal.settings unsafe-paste-alert true
```

Comment: They should add an option to configure it from the UI, perhaps elementary-tweaks will handle that

Comment: @opensas elementary Tweaks is not maintained anymore and not recommended by the devs.

Answer (score 6):

@crow is totally right, another way of doing the same thing is using the `dconf-editor`

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

then open it from Slingshot > Dconf Editor

Go to path, `org` > `pantheon` > `terminal` > `settings` > `unsafe paste alert`

[image]

Uncheck the unsafe-paste-alert.

Comment: This answer is, I believe, better since one gets an idea of what is happening. crow's answer is perfectly valid, but it hides everything behind some commands that, for most users, are completely obscure.