# Warning message while copy&paste commands from internet

Tags: release-freya, pantheon-terminal

When I try to copy and paste a command from net I faced this warning in freya.

The command is adding a PPA. First I thought, the warning  is with that particular web page. But the *exact* message is when I try to copy command and try to  paste in terminal, I am getting warning message.

[image: Imgur]

Comment: see here to disable the warning message : https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/148/how-do-i-disable-the-sudo-paste-warning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means the command has **sudo** in it, when a command that requires **root** access is copy pasted, elementary os shows that warning(not an error) so if you are sure you know what the command does, hit **paste anyway**.

Comment: oh let me edit my post--I edited title forgot to change in body "error"-->warning

Comment: You can disable this warning message in dconf editor or with the following command: `gsettings set org.pantheon.terminal.settings unsafe-paste-alert "false"`. But this is not recommended!