# How to change Text Color in Scratch Freya built in text editor?

Tags: release-freya, code, color-format

How to change the color of texts in the scratch default text editor. It looks grey, and few other colors. I want to change it like dark black and red, blue like need to change few color schemes.

Is there any settings to change the color schemes. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a different style scheme in `org.pantheon.scratch.settings.style-scheme`

See this link for how to edit a setting in dconf https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/176/37

Schemes are located in `/usr/share/gtksourceview-3.0/styles`
and the preinstalled schemes are

- solarized-light (default)
- classic
- kate
- solarized-dark
- cobalt
- oblivion
- tango

Here are more style-schemes listed https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GtkSourceView/StyleSchemes